# What is the difference between Statsmodels and LogisticRegression in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, statsmodels, kaggle

I'm a novice in Python. I'm working on the Titanic task from kaggle.com. 
Could someone explain me the difference between doing LogisticRegression this way:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
X2=train[['male']]
y2=train['Survived']
logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(X2,y2)
print(logmodel.coef_,logmodel.intercept_)
```

and this way :

```
from patsy import dmatrices
import statsmodels.api as sm 
y3, X3 = dmatrices( 'Survived ~ male', data=train, return_type='dataframe')
mod = sm.Logit(y_train2, X3)
res = mod.fit()
print (res.summary())
```

I hope to get the identical intercept and coefficient. But I've got at first log.reggression the next:

Coefficient=**-2.36631709**   Intercept=**1.04454658**

and for the second one:

Coefficient=**-2.4676**    Intercept=**1.1141**

Why are the coefficients and intercepts are different? **Thanks in advance!**

Comment: There are various reasons. The most prominent being the training method and default hyperparameter settings.

Comment: Thnx, but, could you explain your answer more clearly?)

Comment: in the `sm.Logit(...)` in your code, whats `y_train2`?

Comment: Vivek Kumar, sorry for my erratum, instead of 'y2_train' must be 'y3' of course.